# How to hide some fields in django-admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(..., null=True)
    type = models.CharField(...)
    author = models.CharField(...)
```

I have a simple class in models.py. In admin I would like to hide title of the book (in book details form) when type of the saved book is 1. 
How do this in a simplest way?

Comment: You could create method **Book.get_title_or_nothing** and use it in **BookAdmin** to display it

Comment: Ok, thanks, could you give me some example how to use it in BookAdmin? Because I know generaly the idea, but not exactly, which one of objects I should use, what this function should return.

Comment: The problem is how to get type of the object in definition of BookInline() class in admin?

Comment: Why do you want to hide it? To avoid it been modified, or submitted? Or just mean in the situation the title is useless and hence should be ignored?

Comment: Is useless in some situations and make a disorder for users.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You are to create **admin.py** in your module (probably **book**)

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("pk", "get_title_or_nothing")
```

In **Book** class:

```
class Book:
    ...
    def get_title_or_nothing(self):
        if self.type == WEIRD_TYPE:
            return ""
        return self.title
```

**UPDATED:**

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("pk", "get_title_or_nothing")

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if obj.type == "1":
            self.exclude = ("title", )
        form = super(BookAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        return form
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, but when I put this in BookInline I have error:
get_title_or_nothing' that is missing from the form. 
Have you got any idea?
class BookInline(StackedInline):
    model = Book
    fields = (  'get_title_or_nothing' )

Comment: The point is that I need hide the field of the form, not value in the list. How to change from editable=True to editable=False if the value of other field of this  object is 1.

Comment: Yes, thanks, with BookAdmin class is no problem, but BookInline? 
Where e.g. AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): inlines = [BookInline,]
And how to hide fields of BookInline? Maybe get_formset()? Have you got any idea:)?

Comment: In this case I would not use django-admin, but create my own

Comment: Really, Is it not possible to use django-admin in this situation?

Answer (score 191):

For **Django > 1.8 one can [directly set the fields to be excluded in admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.exclude)**:

```
 class PostCodesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      exclude = ('pcname',)
```

---

Hidden fields are directly defined in Django's ORM by setting the Field attribute: `editable = False`

e.g.

```
class PostCodes(models.Model):
  gisid  = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
  pcname = models.CharField(max_length=32, db_index=True, editable=False)
  ...
```

However, setting or changing the model's fields directly may not always be possible or advantegous. In principle the following `admin.py` setup could work, but won't since [exclude](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.exclude) is an InlineModelAdmin option.

```
class PostCodesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     exclude = ('pcname',)
....
```

A solution working at least in Django 1.4 (and likely later version numbers) is:

```
class PostCodesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
      form = super(PostCodesAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
      del form.base_fields['enable_comments'] 
      return form
```

For the admin list-view of the items, it suffices to simply leave out fields not required:
e.g.

```
class PostCodesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ('id', 'gisid', 'title', )
```

Comment: In Django 1.8 exclude = ('fieldname',) does works with admin.ModelAdmin so one does not have to inherit from InlineModelAdmin anymore.

Comment: Also works in Django 1.6.11. It's actually been there [for quite a while](https://github.com/django/django/commit/c1de41f4d29d15616075ffd474e3aba7adcfc64f) (from v1.0).
It doesn't answer the question asked here, but it solved mine :)

Answer (score 8):

```py
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ("fieldname",)  # hide fields which you want
```

Comment: It needs community edit for indentation.

Answer (score 4):

I tried to override `get_form()` function but some mix up errors occur when I switch in different records. I found there is a `get_exclude()` function we can override.

Use:

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_exclude(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj and obj.type == "1":
            # When you create new data the obj is None
            return ("title", )
        return super().get_exclude(request, obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apropos @Lorenz @mrts answer

with Django 2.1 I found that exclude does not work if the field is already specified via fields = .

In that case you may use

```
self.fields.remove('title')
```

fields will have to be defined as a list [] for this to work

Comment: Where do you add this?

Comment: This would be in admin.py. Inside the class extending admin.ModelAdmin, you will need a get_form function. `def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):` `self.fields.remove()` can be called there

Comment: Thanks. I thought the clarification would be useful for anyone else reading this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain the value in the form (for example set a value, i.e. user, based on the request) and hide the field, you can change the widget to `forms.HiddenInput()`:

```py
from django import forms

...

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        """Set defaults based on request user"""
        # update user field with logged user as default
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form.base_fields["user"].initial = request.user.id
        form.base_fields["user"].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
        return form
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj):
        if obj is None:
            return [
                (
                    None,
                    {'fields': ('type', 'description',)}
                )
            ]
        elif request.user.is_superuser:
            return [
                (
                    None,
                    {'fields': ('type', 'status', 'author', 'store', 'description',)}
                )
            ]
        else:
            return [
                (
                    None,
                    {'fields': ('type', 'date', 'author', 'store',)}
                )
            ]
```