# Django admin: Show/Hide field on select any one dropdown value

Tags: jquery, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

models.py:

```
class Plan(models.Model):
    PLAN_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('global', 'Global'),
        ('user specific', 'User Specific'),
    )
    name_of_plan = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False, blank=False)
    number_of_months = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)
    type_of_plan = models.CharField(choices=PLAN_TYPE_CHOICES)
    specific_users = models.ManyToManyField(User, db_index=True)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Plan

class PlanAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Plan

admin.site.register(Plan, PlanAdmin)
```

In admin page I have type_of_plan with choices: "Global", "User Specific"... When I select "User Specific" value I need to show specific_users field And when I select "Global" value I need to hide specific_users field... How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

In the `admin.py` create class `PlanAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)` and implement your logic for getting admin form in the `get_form` function.

For details and example implementation, see this more general question: [How to hide some fields in django-admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330916/how-to-hide-some-fields-in-django-admin)

Comment: [How to hide some fields in django-admin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330916/how-to-hide-some-fields-in-django-admin)
This solution doesn't work for me because my question is "Is possible to show and hide some fields in admin panel based on choice in type_of_plan field (using JQuery or something else)?"

Comment: you can implement that logic in the `get_form` function